# Bleu Score in Model Evaluation Metric

Tags: keras, seq2seq, bleu

In many seq2seq implementations, I saw that they use **accuracy metric** in compiling the model and **Bleu score** only in predictions.

Why they don't use Bleu score in training to be more efficient? if I understand correctly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bilingual Evaluation Understudy Score was meant to replace humans, hence the word understudy comes in it's name.

Now, When you are training your data, you already have the targeted value and you can directly compare your generated output with it, but when you predict on a dataset, you don't have a way to measure if the sentence you translated into is correct. That is why you use Bleu, because no human can check after each machine translation if what you predicted is correct or not, and Bleu provides a sanity check.

P.S. Understudy means someone learning from a mentor to replace him if need be, Bleu "learns" from humans and then is able to score the translation.

For further reference check out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9ZvTxChwg9A&list=PL1w8k37X_6L_s4ncq-swTBvKDWnRSrinI&index=28

If any queries, comment below.

Comment: "Understudy" is not the main reason the metrics is not reported during training. When the reference (i.e. ground-truth) text is available, you can compute the metrics any time.

The main reason would be the metrics is based on the whole corpus, and it would be slow and time consuming to compute it frequently.

Comment: So what exactly is accuracy in this case? If the output is 'I am good' and the reference is 'I am OK' will this be marked as accurate or not? I can understand how BLEU would score this, but not sure how accuracy works here